# Enterprise Application or Web Application for web service

Tags: web-services, enterprise

what are the advantages of either using a enterprise application or a web application to create a web service in netbeans?
All the examples I have researched are using web applications to hold the web service. I have only found one that uses an enterprise application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, since I'm not NetBeans user, but I'm getting that "enterprise application" means "EJB".

"Web application" makes me think of a SOAP or REST or RPC-XML web service.

If I'm correct, then I'd say that you should prefer the web application if there's a chance that non-Java clients will want to use that service.  Web services use HTTP as their communication protocol.  There are no restrictions on client implementation that way.

Comment: This demonstration is combining both applications. "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_0gGL2C1ys&feature=player_embedded". He doesn't explain exactly why the combination is implemented.

Comment: It's possible to do both.  I'm not an EJB fan - I use Spring - so I'd take the web service route.